# Error while indexing data to elastic using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Scenario : I am trying to index json data into elastic . I am getting an error like

> 17:13:38.146 [main] ERROR
>   com.opnlabs.lighthouse.elastic.ElasticSearchIndexer -
>   {"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't
>   merge a non object mapping
>   [map.audits.map.font-size.map.details.map.items.myArrayList.map.selector]
>   with an object mapping
>   [map.audits.map.font-size.map.details.map.items.myArrayList.map.selector]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't
>   merge a non object mapping
>   [map.audits.map.font-size.map.details.map.items.myArrayList.map.selector]
>   with an object mapping
>   [map.audits.map.font-size.map.details.map.items.myArrayList.map.selector]"}

What is causing the issue ? Please help

Code

```
JSONObject newJsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject log = jsonObject.getJSONObject("audits");
            JSONObject log1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("categories");
            newJsonObject.put("audits", log);
            newJsonObject.put("categories", log1);
            newJsonObject.put("timeStamp", time);
            Index index = new Index.Builder(newJsonObject).index(mongoIndexName+"1").type("data").build();
            DocumentResult a = client.execute(index);
```

Basically i m trying to add 3 json values into elastic index. Please help me with what i m doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that you are trying to change an existing mapping. However, that is not possible in Elasticsearch. Once a mapping has been created, it cannot be changed.

[As explained by Shay Banon himself](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/update-mapping/7517/2):

> You can't change existing mapping type, you need to create a new index
>   with the correct mapping and index the data again.

So you must create a new index to create this mapping. Depending on the situation, you either

- create an additional index, or
- delete the current index and re-create it from scratch.

Of course in the latter case you will lose all data in the index, so prepare accordingly.

Taken from here : [Can’t merge a non object mapping with an object mapping error in machine learning(beta) module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435624/can-t-merge-a-non-object-mapping-with-an-object-mapping-error-in-machine-learnin)