# How to create a sub object in Elastic-search 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

Earlier I was using 1.x version and was creating the sub objects mapping using below syntax.

```
"foo": {
            "type": "integer",
            "doc_values": true
        },
"foo.bar": {
            "type": "integer",
            "doc_values": true
        },
"foo.bar.baz": {
            "type": "integer",
            "doc_values": true
        },
```

But now when I am using same mapping syntax in ES 7.x I am getting below error:-

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Can't merge a non object mapping [foo] with an object mapping [foo]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Can't merge a non object mapping [foo] with an object mapping [foo]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I am came accros this SO post [Can’t merge a non object mapping with an object mapping error in machine learning(beta) module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435624/can-t-merge-a-non-object-mapping-with-an-object-mapping-error-in-machine-learnin) But, **Note I am not updating the mapping, instead I am crating a new mapping still getting this error, please advise what to do?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of object type. Refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) for more info

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": { 
      "user": { 
        "properties": {
          "age":  { "type": "integer" },
          "name": { 
            "properties": {
              "first": { "type": "text" },
              "last":  { "type": "text" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In below name can be defined as object and further properties can be added using name.firstname etc. In your mapping foo is of type integer and then you are adding foo.bar so it is throwing error. foo must be of type object.

```
"properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "type" : "object"
            },
            "name.firstname":{
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "name.lastname":{
              "type" : "text"
            }
        }
```

Comment: I looked into this, but then in this format, I have to change a lot, I wanted to know if there is any possibility that it works with existing format

Comment: Thanks for providing some simple syntax, but It would still require some changes and I would like to know why it worked in ES 1.x while I don't see there is any breaking changes in this regard

Comment: In 1.x  mapping syntax is similar to 7 . I am not able to understand how it worked. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/complex-core-fields.html

Comment: Exactly thats my worry as it involve lot of syntax change which I want to avoid

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/dots-in-names.html.  According to this article you will have to update mapping to object type

Comment: One trivial solution could be to replace . with _ in field names and in subsequently in search queries. Please upvote if this helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195238/discussion-between-user7851946-and-jaspreet-chahal).